# How to login user with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Anyone can help me login user with Laravel, this is my try:

```
public function execute($hasCode){
    if(!$hasCode) return $this -> getAuthorizationFrist();  
    $user = $this->socialite->driver('facebook')->user();
    echo $user->getNickname();
    echo $user->getName();
    echo $user->getEmail();
    echo $user->getAvatar();


    $login = new Guard(); 
    $login ->loginUsingId(1);

}
```

This is error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, none given, called
>   in /home/comment/public_html/bild/app/AuthenticateUser.php on line 31
>   and defined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just instantiate `Guard` because it has dependencies that need to be injected when creating it. This is the constructor:

```
public function __construct(UserProvider $provider,
                            SessionInterface $session,
                            Request $request = null)
```

You have a few options:

#### 1. Use the facade:

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```

#### 2. Use the IoC container:

```
$auth = app('auth');
$auth->loginUsingId(1);
```

#### 3. Use dependency injection (recommended):

In the constructor of the class you want to use this:

```
public function __construct(\Illuminate\Auth\Guard $guard){
    $this->auth = $guard;
}
```

And in your method:

```
$this->auth->loginUsingId(1);
```

---

If you're getting

> Trait 'Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait'

That sounds a lot like Laravel 4 to me (Laravel 5 doesn't have this trait anymore) is it possible that you are migrating your application? Take a look at the new [default `User` model on github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Auth Facade:

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```

[Relevant laravel docs article](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication)

Comment: geting some errors when use Auth: Trait 'Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait' not found